# Sugar ORM ArrayList<String>

Tags: android

I have a simple property:

```
private ArrayList<String> _names;
```

It's so simple I really don't want to have to create another class just to house the data.

Is there a way I can persist a list of strings using Sugar ORM in Android?

When I try it currently it seems to be returning null, so just doing it as above doesn't seem sufficient.

Any ideas are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Have you read over this issue? https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/60 Otherwise, Realm does allow you to do this.

Comment: Ah thanks, I hadn't seen that. Looks like I'll need to find an alternative option.

Comment: Like I said, Realm. https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#many-to-many

Comment: You can also use JDXA ORM to persist a list of Strings. http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html